# How can i set the min and max value in a JDateChooser?

Tags: java, max, javafx-8, min, jdatechooser

I saw there's another question like this but the answer isn't useful for me since I added the JDateChooser with the design option in NetBeans, so I don't know how to set the min and max date for the pick.

Comment: Then just add a comment to the existing question. It's not necessary to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming JDateChooser uses an extends of the SpinnerDateModel then you just need to get the model and set the start and end date.

```
SpinnerDateModel model = (SpinnerDateModel) chooser.getModel();
model.setStart(startDate)
model.setEnd(endDate);
```